# 'C:\blp\API\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla'! keeps adding itself onto my Excel Formula

Tags: excel, bloomberg, vba

I have Bloomberg Excel Add-In installed on my computer and I have a VBA Function that check if the file exists in a folder:

```
Function FileExists(sPath As String)
    FileExists = Dir(sPath) <> ""
End Function
```

I use that as part of my Excel cell formula. E.g.:

```
=FileExists([File_Name.xlsx])
```

And this returns me either `True` or `False`

This works fine by itself. However, from time to time when I open the file, I would find the formula becoming `='C:\blp\API\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla'!FileExists([File_Name.xlsx])` for no apparent reason whatsoever and this results in error.

Anyone else experienced this problem before? Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: It sounds like it's trying to access the add-in while it isn't open. When this happens, can you check if the add-in itself has opened and is working correctly?

Comment: I am experiencing similar issue with all CAISSA Excel custom functions e.g. CAISSA.BENCHMARK.ID(). They all get prefixed and modified in this way 'C:\blp\API\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla'!_xldudf_CAISSA_BENCHMARK_ID(). Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a look in the `BloombergUI.xla` file. Could be wrong here but I found `FileExist` to be an internal check for the plugin. So Excel confuses my custom function with the plugin's function.

Long story short, to solve this problem just simply change custom function name. It's been about a month so far with no more `='C:\blp\API\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla'!` issues.